# How to export data from MySQL database into .flr or .pl file in a specific format

Tags: java, mysql, prolog

I'm trying to fetch data from MySQL database into a file in a format that Prolog can read which is like a JSON format but I did not get how to do line break and also when I am uploading to MySQL database it automatically saves into the file.

This code is fetching from database into a file but just on a straight line not the specific format required

```
    JSONArray jObj= new JSONArray();
        jObj.add("id->"+id  );      
        jObj.add("faculty->"+faculty );            
        jObj.add("department->"+department );       
        jObj.add("capacity-> "+capacity  );               
        jObj.add("type-> "+type );               
        obj.add(id +":classroom");              
        obj.add(jObj);

         try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter(textName)) {                       
           while(obj.iterator().hasNext())            
           file.write(obj.toJSONString());
```

I expect the output to be

```
cmpe025: Classroom          
   [
       location-> cmpe_building,
       capacity-> 70 ,
       inDepartment-> cmpe_department,
       roomNumber-> cmpe025
   ].

cmpe026: Classroom 
   [
       location-> cmpe_building,
       capacity-> 70 ,
       inDepartment-> cmpe_department,
       roomNumber-> cmpe026
   ].
```

but the actual output I get is without line break

```
{ "Classroom" ["location->"cmpe_building"capacity-> 70,"inDepartment->"cmpe_department, "roomNumber->" cmpe025], ["location->" cmpe_building,"capacity->"70 ,"inDepartment->" cmpe_department, "roomNumber->" cmpe026].
```

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: If you can control the output, then you should consider using (for instance) a CSV library such as [csv](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=csv) for SWI. If you cannot control the output, you should consider using DCG rules to parse this format.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment posted as an answer because it is to large to be a comment and doesn't answer the question, it proposes a better solution that is not requested.

If you want Prolog to be able to use the data you output, then put it in a means that is easy for Prolog to use; create [facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Rules_and_facts), e.g.

Filename: `classroom.pl`

```
classroom(cmpe025,cmpe_building,70,cmpe_department).
classroom(cmpe026,cmpe_building,70,cmpe_department).
```

Notice that with Prolog facts you don't include the value names, Prolog uses position to identify the values. The facts themselves do need a name, e.g. `classroom` to be able to uniquely identify them as opposed to say a `person` set of facts.

Then in Prolog you can just load the file using [consult/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=consult/1), e.g.

```
consult("C:/classroom.pl").
```

and use it in a [predicate](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/concepts). You will have to create the predicates in a separate file as you would source code.

Filename: `predicates.pl`

```
test :-
  classroom(Course,Building,Room,Department),
  write("Course: "),write(Course),nl,
  write("Building: "),write(Building),nl,
  write("Room: "),write(Room),nl,
  write("Department: "),write(Department).
```

The line

```
classroom(Course,Building,Room,Department)
```

reads the values from the classroom facts. No need to parse the data, reformat, etc.

Using [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/)

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.3.35)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

1 ?- consult("C:/predicates.pl").
true.

2 ?- consult("C:/classroom.pl").
true.

3 ?- test.
Course: cmpe025
Building: cmpe_building
Room: 70
Department: cmpe_department
true ;
Course: cmpe026
Building: cmpe_building
Room: 70
Department: cmpe_department
true.
```

---

While I would not recommend this you can also create the facts on one line in the file, just make sure there is a space between the end of one fact `.` and the start of the next fact `classroom`,
e.g. `). classroom(`

```
classroom(cmpe025,cmpe_building,70,cmpe_department). classroom(cmpe026,cmpe_building,70,cmpe_department).
```